# как правильно вытащить данные из cvs leaflet. Не правильно показывает объекты на карте

Tags: javascript, html, openstreetmap, leafletjs

в этом коде создается карта и добавляется два стиля карты,методом omnivore вытаскиваю данные из cvs,но почему то все объекты  ушли за карту [image: Объекты ушли за карту]`var map = L.map('mapid', {
center: [53.19, 50.02],
zoom: 1,
scrollWheelZoom: false
});

```
    var controlLayers = L.control.layers( null, null, {
     position: "topright",
     collapsed: false
    }).addTo(map);

    var light = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>'
    }).addTo(map); 
    controlLayers.addBaseLayer(light, 'Carto Light basemap');
  
    var terrain = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a>. Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">ODbL</a>.'
    }); 

    controlLayers.addBaseLayer(terrain, 'Stamen Terrain basemap');
   
    var customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
      onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Title);
        }
    });
  
    var runLayer = omnivore.csv('./portals.csv', null, customLayer)
        .on('ready', function() {
        
            map.fitBounds(runLayer.getBounds());
        })
        .addTo(map);

  
    console.log(runLayer);`
```

Есть вариант что он берет id объекта как координаты, не пойму почему так.
[image: console.log взятых объектов из csv]
cvs строки выглядят так :
id_entrance;meetcode;name_ru;name_en;id_station;direction;lat;lon;max_width;min_step;min_step_ramp;lift;lift_minus_step;min_rail_width;max_rail_width;max_angle;escalator;time
14800;1;"шоссе Энтузиастов, кинотеатр ""Факел""";"shosse Entuziastov, cinema ""Fakel""";82;in;55.7516306;37.7162886;740;43;15;0;0;290;690;19;1;203
14801;1;"шоссе Энтузиастов, кинотеатр ""Факел""";"shosse Entuziastov, cinema ""Fakel""";82;out;55.7516306;37.7162886;740;43;10;0;0;350;690;19;1;203

Comment: на последних скринах видно, что он берет для lat и lng число из id_entrance